# Delete items from project podfile

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I have encountered this problem. I removed some items from the podfile, but the module remains in the project and xcode is not show errors. I tried to remove everything related with pod, reinstalled pod and cleared the project, but module remains. Are there solutions?

Comment: if you have removed the unwanted items from the pod then simply go to terminal and select your project folder and again update the pod

Comment: Did you clean (Ctrl + K)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing to Do , Just Add Pod again in project and remove it from terminal.
Select you project path in terminal and fire below command.

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods-deintegrate cocoapods-clean
$ pod deintegrate
$ pod clean
$ rm Podfile
```

For more detail check below page,

[pod_deintegrate](https://guides.cocoapods.org/terminal/commands.html#pod_deintegrate)

**Edit:-** If you want to add pod again then just type below command in your terminal,

```
pod install
```

Comment: Welcome happy to help.